# Putting Message on IBM Websphere MQ

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I have an application that is required to put a very simple message to a remote Queue.
The Queue used is provided by a 3rd party and its an IBM WebSphere MQ (Version 7.5).

I tried to use `amqmdnet.dll` with the example code below but I understood there should be an MQ Client installed on my server to do this.

So my question:
**Is there any way to put a message in a queue without all these requirements? like a simple REST or SOAP client ?**
I am open to use different languages to implement such a component i just don't want to install a 3rd party application on the server (its a hosting environment)

```
// ===========================================================================
// Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
// 5724-H72
// (c) Copyright IBM Corp. 2003, 2005
// ===========================================================================
using System;
using System.Collections;

using IBM.WMQ;

class MQSample
{
  // The type of connection to use, this can be:-
  // MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_BINDINGS for a server connection.
  // MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT for a non-XA client connection
  // MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_XACLIENT for an XA client connection
  // MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED for a managed client connection
  const String connectionType = MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT;

  // Define the name of the queue manager to use (applies to all connections)
  const String qManager = "your_Q_manager";

  // Define the name of your host connection (applies to client connections only)
  const String hostName = "your_hostname";

  // Define the name of the channel to use (applies to client connections only)
  const String channel = "your_channelname";



  /// <summary>
  /// Initialise the connection properties for the connection type requested
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="connectionType">One of the MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_ values</param>
  static Hashtable init(String connectionType)
  {
    Hashtable connectionProperties = new Hashtable();

    // Add the connection type
    connectionProperties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, connectionType);

    // Set up the rest of the connection properties, based on the
    // connection type requested
    switch(connectionType)
    {
      case MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_BINDINGS:
        break;
      case MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT:
      case MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_XACLIENT:
      case MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED:
        connectionProperties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, hostName);
        connectionProperties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, channel);
        break;
    }

    return connectionProperties;
  }
  /// <summary>
  /// The main entry point for the application.
  /// </summary>
  [STAThread]
  static int Main(string[] args)
  {
    try
    {
      Hashtable connectionProperties = init(connectionType);

      // Create a connection to the queue manager using the connection
      // properties just defined
      MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager, connectionProperties);

      // Set up the options on the queue we want to open
      int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT;

      // Now specify the queue that we want to open,and the open options
      MQQueue system_default_local_queue =
        qMgr.AccessQueue("SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LOCAL.QUEUE", openOptions);

      // Define a WebSphere MQ message, writing some text in UTF format
      MQMessage hello_world = new MQMessage();
      hello_world.WriteUTF("Hello World!");

      // Specify the message options
      MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions(); // accept the defaults,
                                                           // same as MQPMO_DEFAULT

      // Put the message on the queue
      system_default_local_queue.Put(hello_world, pmo);



      // Get the message back again

      // First define a WebSphere MQ message buffer to receive the message
      MQMessage retrievedMessage =new MQMessage();
      retrievedMessage.MessageId =hello_world.MessageId;

      // Set the get message options
      MQGetMessageOptions gmo =new MQGetMessageOptions(); //accept the defaults
                                                          //same as MQGMO_DEFAULT

      // Get the message off the queue
      system_default_local_queue.Get(retrievedMessage,gmo);

      // Prove we have the message by displaying the UTF message text
      String msgText = retrievedMessage.ReadUTF();
      Console.WriteLine("The message is: {0}", msgText);

      // Close the queue
      system_default_local_queue.Close();

      // Disconnect from the queue manager
      qMgr.Disconnect();
    }

    //If an error has occurred in the above,try to identify what went wrong.

    //Was it a WebSphere MQ error?
    catch (MQException ex)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("A WebSphere MQ error occurred: {0}", ex.ToString());
    }

    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("A System error occurred: {0}", ex.ToString());
    }

    return 0;
  }//end of start
}//end of sample
```

Comment: You can use that dll in managed mode standalone with no other dlls required.  Go with v8 or v9 redistributable and take only the dll you mention.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by managed mode ? And i need to connect to version 7.5 not 8, 9

Comment: Thaks .. Id appriciate if you culd elaborate about using it as managed mode..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of picking `MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT` which would cause the `amqmdnet.dll` to function in unmanaged mode and rely on other non-.NET dlls, you can select `MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED` to cause it to function in managed mode which means it does not require any other dlls to function.

At MQ v7.5 even in managed mode you can not use the `amqmdnet.dll` by itself, at that version IBM did not support this configuration.  At IBM MQ v8 and later IBM does support using the `amqmdnet.dll` by itself.  You can download the the MQ v8 or MQ v9 redistributable client from one of the links below.  Just find the `amqmdnet.dll` from the zip file and use it.

MQ is fully backward compatible, it should not be an issue for you to connect to a MQ 7.5 queue manager from a higher version client.  Also note that MQ v7.5 goes out of support on April 30th 2018, to keep support from IBM the 3rd party will need to either upgrade or pay extra money for extended support.

- [IBM MQ v8.0 Client](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24037500)
- [IBM MQ v9.0 Client](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24042176)

Comment: The link is broken.